# how to deal with error:double free or corruption

Tags: c++, double, binary-tree

update: removeNode code revised. No error, could run, but no output. The output should be simply printout the vector in main function. I am still check bug now. Thanks a lot for help. If anyone find anybug,please let me know. Thanks a lot.

=======================

The error I got is `*** glibc detected *** ./bintree: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000727060 ***`

The program is simple do the following step:

- find min value of a binary tree;
- record the min value in a vector;
- delete the node with min value in the tree;
- repeat 1-3 till the tree is empty.

The tree is defined as following, language is c++

```
typedef struct myNode* LPNode;
typedef struct myNode Node;
struct myNode
{
  double key;

  LPNode Left; //left subtree
  LPNode Right; //right subtree
};
```

This is a simple delete node function, since each time the smallest value is deleted. The node is kind like leaf, so not so complicated. compareDouble(double a,double b) will return `true` if `a < b`;`false` if `a > b`

```
    //delete a node
void removeNode(LPNode Root,double min)
{
    if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)) {
        if(Root->Left != NULL) 
            removeNode(Root->Left,min);
        else
            printf("Remove bug!\n");
    }else{
        //delete Root;
        //Root=Root->Right;
            LPNode tmp = MakeNewNode(Root->key);
        tmp->Left = Root->Left;
        tmp->Right = Root->Right;
            delete Root;
    Root=tmp->Right;
    }               
}
```

nmax is initialed as 0, sortedvector is alloacted a vector with space as large as the total nodes in the tree, min is initialed as 99999. minValue will return the min value of tree.

```
    //call minValue to find the min key
    //record the min key in a vector
    //call removeNode to delete the Node
    //repeat till the tree is empty
    void problem1(LPNode Root,double* sortedvector,int& nmax)
    {
        double min = MAX;
        while(Root!=NULL)
        {
            sortedvector[nmax] = minValue(Root,min) ;
            nmax++;
            removeNode(Root,min);
        }
        printf("The tree is empty");
    }
```

Comment: `delete Root; Root=Root->Right;` This is really bad. You `delete` something, then in the next line try to access one of its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be much better of using `std::unique_ptr`s to your nodes rather than `LPNode`s.  Then you don't have to even *do* any `delete`s, let alone chase down bugs due to them.  One of your bugs is using `Root` after you've `delete`d it:

```
delete Root;
Root=Root->Right;
```

you need something more like:

```
NewRoot = Root->Right;
delete Root;
Root = NewRoot;
```

Comment: Thx. but for some reason I need to use LPNode and the node is defined fine with other function, such as insert. Just I am so sure to figure out the delete node function.

Comment: Besides the above mentioned issue, as I think, `Root=Root->Right;` does nothing. To change pointer you should pass pointer to pointer into the function

Comment: thx, it helps. Although there still something wrong but no error now.